# Windows 10 creators update vs C# WinForm

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, updates

did someone encounter bad performance problem with WinForm app under this new Windows 10 Creators update thing ? I have a WinForm application and some of the forms inside are now about 40s slower when you try to open them. (not only first opening)
Profiler in VS 2015 told me that main problem is inside of InitializeComponent() at the beginning, so I think it has something to do with this new update. On computer with previous Anniv. update is everything ok.
I know this description is in general, but maybe someone faces something similar.

Comment: Way too broad. Far too many reasons and possible answers. That said, consider that an OS update might reset cached process startup state, slowing things down for awhile until Windows catches up. Or maybe Microsoft broke something and the Winforms DLL isn't in the GAC. Or maybe it's something entirely different. You say that _"some"_ of the forms are slower. What about the rest? What's different? Without more specifics, I don't see how this question is useful. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum; it's a place for _specific_, _answerable_ questions.

Comment: I know what he's talking about; I have the same issue since I installed the Creator Update a few days ago.

Comment: I also have the same issue since I installed the Creator Update. Did you find any answer? It might be due to some changes Microsoft did in .NET 4.7 runtime to improve the High-DPI scaling.

Comment: It's 100% it has something to do with .net 4.7. When I try it in Anniversary Update, mentioned Form works fine, when I install .net 4.7 (stand alone installer is now available for previous w10 version) problems appear.

Comment: Solution for us: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/397